# How do I use a SELECT SQLite statement and output the data as a string?

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe5

Okay so I know how to put data into an SQLite database... But how do I go about returning the value?

Adding data into the database using `TSQLQuery`, which works:

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  noteTitle : string;
begin
  try
    form1.SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('title').AsString := edit1.Text;
    form1.SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('content').AsString := memo1.Text;
    form1.SQLQueryInsert.ExecSQL(); // INSERT INTO notes (id, title, content) VALUES (:id, :title, :content)
    form1.notes.Refresh;
    form2.Edit1.Text := '';
    form2.Memo1.Text := '';
    form2.close;
    form1.Show;
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now in the process to try and accomplish reading from the table, I've made the assumption it's something similar like:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  results : TDataSet;
begin
  if ListView1.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    form3.show();
    SQLQuerySelectTitle.ParamByName('title').AsString := ListView1.Selected.Text;
    SQLQuerySelectTitle.ExecSQL(); //SELECT title FROM notes WHERE title = :title
    form3.memo1.Text := SQLQuerySelectTitle.Fields[0].ToString;
  end;
end;
```

but so far, it just returns list out of bounds error.

Thank you, I could really use some help understanding this, I've tried looking for some information on it but no luck.

Comment: The `ExecSQL` method is for executing queries whose doesn't return any data (like e.g. `INSERT` or `UPDATE`). You should use `Open` method instead. Then to access the field use `Fields[0].AsString` instead of `Fields[0].ToString`. The `ToString` method returns the class name of the current object instance. However, if you're having FireDAC in your Delphi, I'd recommend you to use it rather than dbExpress.

Comment: Ah. Well i tried that 
`SQLQuerySelectTitle.ParamByName('title').AsString := ListView1.Selected.Text;
SQLQuerySelectTitle.Open; //SELECT title FROM notes WHERE title = :title
form3.memo1.Text := SQLQuerySelectTitle.Fields[0].AsString;` and returned no errors, but also no results, it should return "Welcome" as that's the title. I do have FireDAC, i shall look into that, but i have a feeling i will just encounter the same problem.

Comment: Okay well i figured it out! A few alterations was all that was needed! I changed the sql query to `SELECT * FROM notes WHERE title = :title` and the `fields[0]` to `fields[1]`

Thank you for helping TLama! :)

Comment: Wait, that's not a solution. Field indexing starts by 0 and if you explicitly say that you want to select only one column in your query, e.g. as `SELECT title FROM...`, then the `title` field should be accessible through `Fields[0]`. I can't explain why would they change this behavior in Delphi XE5 (or for Android platform specifically) because this worked for ages.

Comment: I'm just developing a simple notepad application just to get grips with using databases for a future assignment. The table's keys are ID, title and content. When i put `fields[1]` it displays title, and `fields[2]` it displays the content and `[0]` for id. Now another issue i've run into is it's only fetching data from the first row, when im try to display the third or fourth row. If i keep messing with it i'll get there eventually.

Comment: Ah... Calling `SQLQuerySelectTitle.Close;` at the end fixed it all completely!

Comment: That's what I overlooked in your code (since I was missing the usual pattern of assigning the SQL query). Now you've just learned by experience :)

Comment: FYI Your exception handling is already implemented by the application (showing the exception) by default

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'content' is the column that you use to populate your memo:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If ListView1.Selected <> nil Then Begin
    form3.show();
    form3.memo1.Lines.Clear;
    With SQLQuerySelectTitle Do Try
      ParamByName('title').AsString := ListView1.Selected.Text;
      Open;
      First;
      While Not Eof Do Begin
        form3.memo1.Lines.Add(FieldByName('content').AsString);
        Next;
      End;
    Finally
      Close;
    End;
  end;
end;
```

Actually I'd rather have the form3.Show after having populated memo1.

The First / While Not Eof / Next is the standard way to read all records of a dataset. Actually just after an Open, you could avoid the First.

Using FieldByName() is more readable and maintenable than using fields[]... but it is a little bit less efficient. You could optimize it by having a var f:TField and executing a single f:=FieldByName after the Open, but before the While loop. In the While loop you can then reference f directly. This is a must if you expect to read thousands of records (but I don't think this is the case here).